# Android phonegap project spamming QTAGUID messages

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I have been having this problem for a while now, and while it doesn't negatively affect my application I would like to fix it if I can. I am not really sure how to describe the problem.

Basically, I have an **Android PhoneGap 1.9 project**, using API 15 (this happened under **API 10** as well) and the LogCat logs have relentless spam from **QTAGUID**, specifically from my application.

```
08-04 14:31:30.092: I/qtaguid(15542): Failed write_ctrl(u 118) res=-1 errno=22
08-04 14:31:30.092: I/qtaguid(15542): Untagging socket 118 failed errno=-22
08-04 14:31:30.092: I/qtaguid(15542): Failed write_ctrl(u 123) res=-1 errno=22
08-04 14:31:30.092: I/qtaguid(15542): Untagging socket 123 failed errno=-22
08-04 14:31:36.338: I/qtaguid(15542): Failed write_ctrl(u 116) res=-1 errno=22
08-04 14:31:36.338: I/qtaguid(15542): Untagging socket 116 failed errno=-22
08-04 14:31:36.368: I/qtaguid(15542): Failed write_ctrl(t 116 43082816946176 1074812240) res=-1 errno=1
08-04 14:31:36.368: I/qtaguid(15542): Tagging socket 116 with tag 272f00000000(10031) for uid 1074812240 failed errno=-1
08-04 14:31:36.368: I/qtaguid(15542): Failed write_ctrl(t 118 43082816946176 1074812240) res=-1 errno=1
08-04 14:31:36.368: I/qtaguid(15542): Tagging socket 118 with tag 272f00000000(10031) for uid 1074812240 failed errno=-1
08-04 14:31:36.378: I/qtaguid(15542): Failed write_ctrl(t 123 43082816946176 1074812240) res=-1 errno=1
08-04 14:31:36.378: I/qtaguid(15542): Tagging socket 123 with tag 272f00000000(10031) for uid 1074812240 failed errno=-1
08-04 14:31:46.388: I/qtaguid(15542): Failed write_ctrl(u 116) res=-1 errno=22
08-04 14:31:46.388: I/qtaguid(15542): Untagging socket 116 failed errno=-22
08-04 14:31:46.388: I/qtaguid(15542): Failed write_ctrl(u 118) res=-1 errno=22
08-04 14:31:46.388: I/qtaguid(15542): Untagging socket 118 failed errno=-22
08-04 14:31:46.388: I/qtaguid(15542): Failed write_ctrl(u 123) res=-1 errno=22
08-04 14:31:46.388: I/qtaguid(15542): Untagging socket 123 failed errno=-22
08-04 14:31:46.438: I/qtaguid(15542): Failed write_ctrl(t 116 43082816946176 825047349) res=-1 errno=1
08-04 14:31:46.438: I/qtaguid(15542): Tagging socket 116 with tag 272f00000000(10031) for uid 825047349 failed errno=-1
08-04 14:31:46.448: I/qtaguid(15542): Failed write_ctrl(t 118 43082816946176 825047349) res=-1 errno=1
08-04 14:31:46.448: I/qtaguid(15542): Tagging socket 118 with tag 272f00000000(10031) for uid 825047349 failed errno=-1
08-04 14:31:46.448: I/qtaguid(15542): Failed write_ctrl(t 123 43082816946176 825047349) res=-1 errno=1
08-04 14:31:46.448: I/qtaguid(15542): Tagging socket 123 with tag 272f00000000(10031) for uid 825047349 failed errno=-1
08-04 14:31:56.458: I/qtaguid(15542): Failed write_ctrl(u 116) res=-1 errno=22
08-04 14:31:56.458: I/qtaguid(15542): Untagging socket 116 failed errno=-22
08-04 14:31:56.458: I/qtaguid(15542): Failed write_ctrl(u 118) res=-1 errno=22
08-04 14:31:56.458: I/qtaguid(15542): Untagging socket 118 failed errno=-22
08-04 14:31:56.458: I/qtaguid(15542): Failed write_ctrl(u 123) res=-1 errno=22
08-04 14:31:56.458: I/qtaguid(15542): Untagging socket 123 failed errno=-22
08-04 14:31:56.508: I/qtaguid(15542): Failed write_ctrl(t 116 43082816946176 771781733) res=-1 errno=1
08-04 14:31:56.508: I/qtaguid(15542): Tagging socket 116 with tag 272f00000000(10031) for uid 771781733 failed errno=-1
08-04 14:31:56.508: I/qtaguid(15542): Failed write_ctrl(t 118 43082816946176 771781733) res=-1 errno=1
08-04 14:31:56.508: I/qtaguid(15542): Tagging socket 118 with tag 272f00000000(10031) for uid 771781733 failed errno=-1
08-04 14:31:56.518: I/qtaguid(15542): Failed write_ctrl(t 123 43082816946176 771781733) res=-1 errno=1
08-04 14:31:56.518: I/qtaguid(15542): Tagging socket 123 with tag 272f00000000(10031) for uid 771781733 failed errno=-1
```

This happens in two project I've worked on. The older one was meant to get my feet wet with PhoneGap development. That project was very simple and had nothing advanced in it. Basically all it would do is POST to a website, and process the response. It was purely developed on the javascript side. It spams the same QTAGUID messages.

The projects are both `jquery 1.7 / jquerymobile 1.1.1` and cordova. (Old project is **cordova 1.6**, new one is 1.9)

I've been researching this for a while now and haven't found any relevant information regarding it. Any insight would be appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Sounds like there's an issue with the kernel and iptables? What android version are you using?

Comment: 4.0.3, ICS I have an HTC Evo 3D, on the Rogers network (Canada)

Comment: This also only happens with my 2 projects. I do not get a message from any other running application in regards to QTAGUID.

Comment: Are you using Wifi? I get this on my htc one if i'm using wifi, but not when I'm connected via cable or 3g. I never get it on my old htc desire... I couldn't track it any furter though. sorry.

Comment: as an FYI I am getting a few of these in my app as well, using wifi as well, but mine is pure android, no phonegap code.   It's listed in a green font in eclipse, so it's not an error, but not sure what's causing it.  4.0.4 HTC ONE X

Comment: After all this time I haven't had any progress with this, but I do like hearing that it is not a phonegap issue. Narrows the playing field a bit. I will say, I certainly get more than "a few" messages. It really does live up to the title when I say spamming. Oh and yes, I am using WiFi. I have a very minimal data plan so I haven't tried anything else.

Comment: To add context, it seems qtaguid is related to socket tagging that are used for the purpose of accounting data usage and enforcing network quotas: http://source.android.com/tech/datausage/tags-explained.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a WiFi issue and enabling "Avoid poor connections" (Settings, Wireless, WiFi, menu Advanced) sometimes help. I had the same problem only using WiFi networks. You can also try this application [WiFi Connection Fixer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=co.in.zextr.wcf) but as far as i know there is nothing you can do about it in your code.

Comment: Hmmm, I'm going to accept this because I think you are right. I don't have that exact setting, but a quick search revealed this is often labeled as WI-FI Performance or WI-FI Optimization. I flipped that setting and I am not currently seeing that spam in Eclipse. Didn't expect a solution to this old question! Thanks!