# Logcat error - qtaguid - Failed write_ctrl

Tags: android

I've got an Android app that has been working fine on a HTC Sensation (4.0.3) but after some recent changes (specifically adding a table to the database for persistant storage & some general code changes) I'm getting this really unusual error msg in the logcat (see below) which I can't find any info on apart from this one other SO question > [Android phonegap project spamming QTAGUID messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11811127/droidgap-project-spamming-qtaguid-messages) .

The side effect is that a certain set of data is not loading correctly in the app (although other data does load from certain web service calls)

I get the issue specifically when connected to wifi and after testing it on 3g I don't get the error in the logcat but the data in question doesn;t load in the app.

If anyone has seen this error before or know what it might be related to, please let me know. Thanks.

Logcat example output:

```
03-26 09:32:05.554: I/qtaguid(1168): Failed write_ctrl(t 144 42958262894592 1408305917) res=-1 errno=1
03-26 09:32:05.554: I/qtaguid(1168): Tagging socket 144 with tag 271200000000(10002) for uid 1408305917 failed errno=-1
03-26 09:32:05.554: I/qtaguid(1168): Failed write_ctrl(t 145 42958262894592 1408305917) res=-1 errno=1
03-26 09:32:05.554: I/qtaguid(1168): Tagging socket 145 with tag 271200000000(10002) for uid 1408305917 failed errno=-1
03-26 09:32:05.554: I/qtaguid(1168): Failed write_ctrl(t 146 42958262894592 1408305917) res=-1 errno=1
03-26 09:32:05.554: I/qtaguid(1168): Tagging socket 146 with tag 271200000000(10002) for uid 1408305917 failed errno=-1
03-26 09:32:05.564: I/qtaguid(1168): Failed write_ctrl(t 147 42958262894592 0) res=-1 errno=1
03-26 09:32:05.564: I/qtaguid(1168): Tagging socket 147 with tag 271200000000(10002) for uid 0 failed errno=-1
03-26 09:32:05.564: I/qtaguid(1168): Failed write_ctrl(t 148 42958262894592 0) res=-1 errno=1
03-26 09:32:05.564: I/qtaguid(1168): Tagging socket 148 with tag 271200000000(10002) for uid 0 failed errno=-1
03-26 09:32:05.564: I/qtaguid(1168): Failed write_ctrl(t 149 42958262894592 0) res=-1 errno=1
03-26 09:32:05.564: I/qtaguid(1168): Tagging socket 149 with tag 271200000000(10002) for uid 0 failed errno=-1
```

Answer (score 3):

I've just done a factory reset on the HTC Sensation and then re-installed the app and this has solved the issue!

I also found this information on the Android Open Source website refering to the 'qtaguid' process in the kernal that is probabily related to the error > http://source.android.com/tech/datausage/kernel-overview.html .

I'm still not sure what has actually caused the error thou, so if anyone has experienced a similar error or found a reason for it then I'd love to know!